# Get the cropped areas of game in LibGDX's fill viewport

Tags: libgdx

I am developing a game for android using LibGDX and i am using Fill viewport to handle different aspect ratios. 
I would like to know how to get the cropped areas in pixels, since fill viewport crops part of the game.
I checked the libgdx API docs and only found the get gutter methods which work only for fit viewport.

Comment: I have solved the problem. What i did is i calculated the aspect ratio of the device, then multiplied the aspect ratio by the viewport height to get the new height. Then i subracted the new height from the viewport height and divided it by 2 to get the exact edges of the screen.